# selecting random json element

Tags: python, json

**python 3.5**

hi i have following json file and i want to select json data random...

**json**

```
{"x":[
    {"A":"B"},
    {"A":"C"},
    {"F":"H"}
]}
```

select data where item in data['x'] is A

(result would be C or B)

**code**

```
data = json.load(open('j.json'))
x = ""
for item in data["x"]:
    T = True if "A" in item else False
    if T is True:
        x = item["A"]
        #break
    else:
        pass
if x == "":
    print("nothing found")
else :
    print(x)
```

when i break it , it just prints B every time i run script
i want it to select B or C random 
any ideas?!

Comment: Just write `if "A" in item:`.

Comment: How is this selection random?

Comment: What's the problem? I ran your script, it printed `C`.

Comment: Hello, Mohammad. Welcome to [so]! SO is a question-and-answer site. Readers such as yourself ask questions and other readers try to provide answers. You seem to be missing the essential element of an SO post -- the question!  Do you have a specific programming question to ask?

Comment: sorry for bad asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this program will answer your (not-yet-asked) question:

```
import json
import random

data = json.load(open('j.json'))
values = [v for d in data['x'] for k,v in d.items() if k == 'A']
try:
    x = random.choice(values)
    print(x)
except IndexError:
    print("nothing found")
```